# How to store multiple uploaded files with Laravel's Storage Facade

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I have a project that is running Laravel 5.8 and I am trying to use a form that allows user's to upload their own images to the site and store it in the public folder. When trying to use the Storage facade with the 'put' method, a path gets returned but the images do not actually get stored.

```php
if ($request->hasfile('images')) {
    foreach ($request->file('images') as $file) {
        $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('images', $file);
        echo $path;
    }
}
```

This is the code I am trying to use. The path gets echo'd as it should and I have not made any changes to the filesystem config. In the form, the input field images allows for submitting multiple files and the form does has`enctype="multipart/form-data"`. The `$file` variable also contains an instance of `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile`.

The previous code I used which did work was:

```php
if ($request->hasfile('images')) {
    foreach ($request->file('images') as $file) {
        $file->move(public_path('images'), $file->getClientOriginalName());
    }
}
```

I would be okay with using my previous code if Laravel can give it a unique file name on upload but what would be causing my code with the Storage facade to not save the images properly? Does the put function just not work like that or is there something I am overlooking?

**Edit:**
So I realise the images were in fact saving correctly as they should be. I was looking inside the `public` folder rather than the `storage` folder which is why my second code example 'worked' but not the first. I realise when using the Storage facade I need to make use of Symbolic linking if I want to access these files on the web.

Comment: There's [documentation on File Uploads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#storing-files). Scroll down a little to "_File Uploads_". See if that helps

Comment: @kerbholz thanks, I have taken a look at the docs. To my understanding the only way to save things to a local/public disk is with `put`, `putFile` and then the `store`, but none of these seem to work. I'm guessing it isn't an error with my code and actually something that I have not set up properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also make sure you have created the symbolic link on your Ubuntu server or Windows development machine to the storage folder.

Windows you can use : `mklink /j /path/to/laravel/public/youfolder /path/to/laravel/storage/youfolder`

Ubuntu: `ln -s /path/to/laravel/public/youfolder /path/to/laravel/storage/youfolder`

To check & set you can also use use `php artisan storage:link`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
  if ($request->hasfile('images')) {
        foreach ($request->file('images') as $file) {
            $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('images', $file);
            $new_file_name = time() . "_" . uniqid() . "_" . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = Storage::disk('public')->put($new_file_name, file_get_contents($file));
           echo $path;
       }
 }
```

Comment: When echoing out `$path` it does display a true, but the problem is the `Storage::put()` doesn't actually seem to do anything. Because the files are not actually being stored in any of the directories. This could simply be due to a configuration issue maybe? It doesn't seem to work in my local environment either.

Comment: why you can't use  this :   "copy($image->getRealPath(), public_path('images/' . $new_file_name));"

Comment: Using `copy()` or `move()` both do the trick but didn't feel like they were the correct way to be saving it. I also wanted Laravel to handle the unique naming of the images rather than doing it myself. I'm just not too sure what is preventing the facade's `put()` function from working.